# Have to go vs will have to go

Tags: grammar

Since we're talking about a scheduled appointment, which option is correct? Why? Is the other one always incorrect when taking about scheduled appointments?

I'm sorry, but next Tuesday after school I **have / will have** to go to football training.

Answer (score 2):

There's probably no scope for any difference in meaning with OP's exact example. Unless we want to note that the ***I have*** version primarily alludes the fact that *I **currently** have that future commitment*, whereas ***I will have*** refers a ***future*** obligation. It's the same obligation, so I don't see how we can make much of a distinction there.

HOWEVER - there are contexts where there's a more "palpable" distinction...

> *We're going on a pub crawl tonight, but I [**have to** | **will have to**] be the designated driver.*

In *that* context, ***I have to...*** implies that commitment is already known to some / all of speaker's drinking companions. But ***I will have to...*** tends to imply that the others aren't yet aware that the speaker is the one who will have to remain sober. Presumably the *speaker* is already resigned to the fact that he ***will*** lose the argument when they have to decide who stays sober.